# Namespace name IRequestManager could not be found

Tags: .net, json, get

I have the following code which I am using to try and get data from my MangoApps application. I am following this guide as I am quite new to this https://github.com/gibran/MangoSpring.Net/blob/master/README.md but I am getting a Namespace name IRequestManager could not be found error. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

```
using MangoSpring.Net;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Project1
{


class DataGet
{
    public DataGet()
    {

        var authenticationToken = new AuthenticationToken(_domainName, _username, _password, _apiKey);
        IRequestManager manager = new RequestManager();

        // logging in
        manager.Login(authenticationToken);

        // calling a method (ex: Get All Projects)
        var allProjects = manager.Execute(new GetAllProjectsMethod());

        // logging out (optional)
        manager.Logout();
    }


    public class GetAllProjectsMethod : MangoSpringMethod
    {
        public GetAllProjectsMethod()
        {
            HttpMethod = "GET";
            ShouldRunAuthenticated = true;
            Path = "projects.json?all=true";
        }
    }


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the error, it appears that the error is on the client side and the API call to MangoApps is *not* getting made.

Anyway to check with the author of the client package about it ? - https://www.nuget.org/packages/MangoSpring.Net

Thanks!

Comment: But the error occurs before I execute. It continues with 'are you missing a directive or an assembly reference?'